# Problem at linking libxml2 library in my C project

Tags: c, gcc, static-libraries

I want to use the libxml2 C library in a project (I'm on Windows, and using gcc in CMD). I am trying to include it (as a static library) in a source file, so I can use its functions. But, gcc is having problems to find the header files of the library. So, how can I configure gcc compilation, so that it can finds the necessary header files?

My folder structure:

```
root
|
|--test.c
|--bin/--libxml2.a
|--lib/--libxml2.lib
|--include/--libxml/
             |--c14v.h
             |--parser.h
             |--xmlstring.h
             |--xmlversion.h
             |... and many other header files
```

As you can see above, I already compiled the library. So, I have its archive (`libxml2.a`) and lib file (`libxml2.lib`), and, all its header file (`include/libxml/`). Right now, I am trying to compile this simple `test.c` file below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "libxml/parser.h"

int main () {
    return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile it with `gcc test.c -o test -I/include/ -L/bin/ -llibxml2` command, I get the following error:

```
test.c:2:10: fatal error: libxml/parser.h: No such file or directory
    2 | #include "libxml/parser.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

In my understanding, I used the `-I` gcc option, because the header files are in `include` folder. But it did not work. So, I tried to eliminate the `include` folder. So my folder structure become:

```
root
|
|--test.c
|--bin/--libxml2.a
|--lib/--libxml2.lib
|--libxml/
   |--c14v.h
   |--parser.h
   |--xmlstring.h
   |--xmlversion.h
   |... and many other header files
```

Now, with `gcc test.c -o test -L/bin/ -llibxml2` I get the same error about a different file. So, gcc can now find `libxml/parser.h`, but it cannot find `libxml/xmlversion.h`, which is one of the many header files in the `libxml` folder.

```
In file included from test.c:2:
libxml/parser.h:15:10: fatal error: libxml/xmlversion.h: No such file or directory
   15 | #include <libxml/xmlversion.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

What I am doing wrong here? Can I pass the `include` folder path to gcc (with `-l` or other option), so it can find all the header files stored in this folder?

Also, am I linking correctly the library with `-l` and `-L` options? There is something I am missing here?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: It's not `-I/include/` it's `-Iinclude/`. Research difference between relative and absolute file paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @KamilCuk pointed out in the comments, I was defining incorrectly the paths in the gcc options. So the correct command that solved the entire problem was:

```
gcc test.c -o test -Iinclude/ -Llib/ -l:libxml2.a
```